# Relations Has Many Through with 3 models - TypeORM

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, typeorm

I have three models: User, Category and Feed.

The first one is **User** and it has a **One to Many** relationship with the second model which is **Category**. Category has a userId column and a Many to One relationship with User.

**Category** has a **One To Many** relationship with the third and last model: **Feed**. Similarly, Feed has a column categoryId and a Many To One relationship with Category.

I want to access the **Feeds** of a certain **categoryId** (for example of categoryId = 2) but only where the **userId** on this category is a certain value too (for example of userId = 1).

This relation is the has_many_through for Ruby on Rails programmers...

How can I build this query using TypeORM ?
Alternatively, if you have an idea on how to write it in pure SQL I'll take it too.

I'm also thinking about creating a column userId directly through Feeds to have a One To Many relationship between User and Feed. Do you think it'll be more optimized to do so ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your model classes for User, Category and Feed? Then it is easy to give you an answer which will work in TypeORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would achieve that through pure SQL, I'm not much help on the TypeORM front unfortunately.

```sql
SELECT f.*
FROM Feeds f
LEFT JOIN Category g
ON f.categoryId = g.categoryId
WHERE f.categoryId = 2
AND g.userId = 1
```